# problemas para usar el helper config de Laravel

Tags: laravel, configuración

en mi carpeta config de mi proyecto laravel 5.5 cree un archivo php nombrado `vars.php`:

```
    <?php

return [
    'mensaje' => '',
];
```

el objetivo de esto es para en cualquier lugar utilizar el valor que pueda almacenar en esa variable y utilizarlo en una vista o controller de este manera `config('vars.mensaje')` pero tengo un problema, le paso información a esa variable de esta manera `config('vars.mensaje', 'Todo Bien');` pero me da un error `500` ya que me da el mensaje error siguiente: `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\config' not found`. una vez solucionado este problema quisiera preguntar si cuando le asigno un valor a la variable de esta forma `config('vars.mensaje', 'Todo Bien');` y recargo la pantalla, este valor nuevo asignado se mantendrá. El tema esta en que intento crear una variable global que me permita asignarle valores y aunque se recargue la pantalla siga con esa información almacenada.

como pued resolver estas inquietudes colegas.

Answer (score 1):

luego de crear el archivo debes ejecutar el comando:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

para que laravel tome el archivo que has creado y luego para acceder a los valores del archivo de configuración:

```
config('vars.mensaje', 'valor_por_defecto')
```

en cuanto a la otra pregunta te recomiendo que guardes el mensaje que quieres en una variable de sesion para que puedas acceder desde cualquier parte de la aplicacion y no se pierda mientras tengas la sesion iniciada en tu aplicacion